# Как узнать кто зашел на сайт под socks4-5 и оставил объявление?

Tags: socks5

Трудно узнать кто пользовался socks4-5?
т.е. зашел на сайт под socks4-5. оставил объявление.

и вот захотел кто-то узнать кто это объявление оставил?
сложно это сделать? учитывай что кучи людей пользуються. 
И скажем socks левый какой-то.

Comment: Никак не узнать если нет доступа к серверу на котором носок поднят.

Comment: Не совсем понял ваш последний пост, в любом случае вы никак не узнаете не имя доступа к серверу о входящих подключениях, а какой там софт установлен и какие права у софта, ведётся ли лог и тд, все это зависит от ситуации, поэтому я не могу вам дать однозначный ответ.

Comment: Ну я так понял там бесплатные прок си, вы ничего не сможете узнать без доступа к серверу на котором этот прокси поднят, а как он там поднят и какие логи там ведутся одному админу известно.

Comment: Поидее с любым портом который не зарезервирован каким либо системным сервисом можно работать как угодно, например пробрасывать траф на этот порт, или наоборот какой то софт установленный в системе слушает внешние коннекты на этот порт, может быть все что угодно. Насчёт бесплатных прокси я ничего вам не могу сказать как они и что там логируется. Хотите быть уверенными в чем либо поднимите сами на сервере свой прокси и работайте.